# How do i can pass my exception from servelet filter to a Spring component

Tags: java, spring, exception, filter

I have a simple implementation of the servletFilter:

```
public class ExceptionHandlerFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        servletResponse.getWriter().write("ERROR");
    } 
}
```

}

And i have custom Spring exception handler:

```
@Component
public class ExceptionHadnler {

@Autowired
//some injected field

public void handle(Throwable t) {
//some hadle logic
}

}
```

I want somehow to call my hadnler from servlet filter, or at least pass my exception to spring-managed class instance. Unfortunally, it's impossible to inject spring beans into servlet filter, because the filter does not managed by Spring.
Is there some way to connect servlet filter and Spring bean?

Comment: cant you use [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) or register the filter using FilterRegistrationBean.

Answer (score 1):

> [FilterRegistrationBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html)
>   extends AbstractFilterRegistrationBean
>   A ServletContextInitializer to register Filters in a Servlet 3.0+ container. Similar to the registration features provided by ServletContext but with a Spring Bean friendly design.
>
> [GenericFilterBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html) Simple base implementation of Filter which treats its config parameters (init-param entries within the filter tag in web.xml) as bean properties.